# Email not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am working on booking app in codeigniter. I am stuck in email sending from localhost.
I am using gmail smtp for sending email. I am using email/booking_email.php view file as email template. But, When I run website page that contains email sending script in localhost, it keeps loading but email is not sent.

```
$email = "atomambition@gmail.com";
$name = "Wiyo HK";
$email_config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'atomambition@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '********',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $email_config);


$this->email->from($email, $name);
$this->email->to($this->bookings_class->get_email());
$this->email->reply_to($email, $name);

$subject = 'This is Booking email from Wiyo HK';
$this->email->subject($subject);
$data = array('customer_name' => 'Avash Poudel');
$message = $this->load->view('email/booking_email', $data, TRUE);
$this->email->message($message);

echo $result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Try smtp_host as `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Try 'smtp_port' => 25

Comment: Sorry !! after i edited my code, it keeps loading as it was earlier. Email is not recieved. After 30 seconds it gave me fatal error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in A:\xampp\htdocs\wiyohk\system\libraries\Email.php on line 1818

Comment: When i change smtp_port to 25, it gave error like this Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Comment: it means your localhost is not supporting it, try to upload it and then test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost does not support sending emails directly unless configured. 
In the localhost it does not work like this . For testing use `mail()` protocol on localhost and `smtp` on server.

Comment: IN ruby on rails, email sending locally was quite easy but not with codeigniter. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: i am afraid i dont have any idea with ruby on rails. May be configuring ruby on rails the localhost is setup automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Add this in $email_config.

After that you need to initialise your config array. 
So write this `$this->email->initialize($email_config);`

Also use `$this->email->print_debugger()` to debug